# Calling function in setup.py (using tox)

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils, tox

I need my `setup.py` to call a function in another file. I know this can be done by settings a `cmdclass` such as:

```
import my_module

class Install(_install):
    def run(self):
        _install.run(self)
        my_module.do_stuff()

setup(name='foo',
        cmdclass={'install': Install},
        )
```

But I'm using [tox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox), which doesn't seem to accept imports from `setup.py` (it just says module can't be found). 
To make tox run, I could just put this in the `tox.ini` instead:

```
commands = path_to_my_module.py
```

and it will run it just fine.

**Problem**

How can I make my `setup.py` call my function without tox complaining about it?

Comment: I don't know what "doesn't seem to accept imports from `setup.py`" could mean. But it sounds like `tox` isn't installed into the site-packages for the Python installation you're using to run `setup.py`. (Since `tox` is a virtual environment tool, it's possible that it intentionally doesn't make itself available in its virtual environments for some reason—but if so, I'm sure this case has to be covered in the docs or FAQ…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tox` creates a virtualenv and installs your module into it. Because dependencies are listed in `setup.py`, they will not be installed until after `setup.py` is called to determine what they are. So at the time that `setup.py` first executes, nothing is installed in your shiny new virtualenv.

Look into using the `deps` configuration option in `tox.ini` as those packages will be installed before the one under test, according to the docs https://testrun.org/tox/latest/config.html

Comment: That makes sense. But I'm not trying to import an external module, I need to import another file from the module that I am about to set up. So it is not a dependency in that sense.

Comment: OK. I misread another file as another package I guess. I went into a small project that I have tox set up for and added a custom install command that calls out to another module in the same directory as `setup.py`. It imports and runs. Make sure everything is up to date? And make sure you are  importing `from setuptools.command.install import install` and NOT `from distutils.command.install import install`, although for me the latter results in a different error.

Comment: Is there any chance at all that my_module isn't being included by your package manifest, and it works in `commands` because it's in your path somewhere?

Comment: The manifest looks fine. I am using distutils though, not setuptools. Why would that be a problem?

Comment: For that specific import, using distutils caused a failure with "option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized" which using setuptools resolved.